# javascript manipulable SVG though ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

How can I get SVG file though ajax without any errors that could be manipulable (selectable) with javascript. When I try simple jQuery get function it looks like works but the problem is with putting content inside div.

when I try it with code like this

```
jQuery.get( "mysvg.svg", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

in console it shows full code, but if I try to put it in DOM I get

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to put it in DOM?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is taking a child array of #document object which is ["documentElement"]

So svg perefectly appends with this jQuery code

```
$.get( "mysvg.svg", function( data ) {
  jQuery("#youdiv").append(data["documentElement"]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the data type to "text" and then append to element.

```
 jQuery.get( "mysvg.svg", null , function( data ) {     
        $('body').append(data);
    },'text');
```